# How to replace entire page in router outlet angular 4 routing?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I want to replace entire page content on image click in angular 4. I have 2 HTML components, want to redirect from one component to other. Both the components are having different header and content.

Please find the SS of both the layouts:
**Home Component Result Layout:**
[image]

**Details Component Result Layout:**
[image]

I want to redirect from home to details on click on home link. As a result, on click of Home component link, details component should appear and home component should hidden.

**Please find my routing of app.module.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { AdminComponent }      from './admin/admin.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/Dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppComponent } from './shell/app.component';
import { AppDetailsComponent } from './app-details/app.details.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'details',
        component: AppDetailsComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo:'/home'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: HomeComponent
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**App.component.html code**

```
<app-home></app-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Home component anchor link to navigate from home to details**

```
<div class="mapContainer" id="MapContainer">
    <div class="CustomMapSize">
        <a routerLink="/details"><img src="../../../local-npm-packages/assets/images/WorldMap.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

On click on a[routerLink="/details"], new details page is opening as expected but parent home layout is not getting hidden.

Can anyone suggest if any issue in my routing?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the the parent home layout is coming from 
<app-home> component which you have given above <router-outlet>,

To replace the entire page, in your **app.component.html** use only the following element:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: HI, can u please elaborate the answer? If only <router-outlet> is used, then what about the UI of AppComponent? Where the clickable image is shown then?

Comment: @AnishMittal Hello, Anish. I have the exact same question as you. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because you made parent-children relationship.
If you want to replace the entire page make it as siblings relationship.

`const appRoutes: Routes = [ { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, { path: 'details', component: AppDetailsComponent } ]` 
And in app.component.html,no need to inject `<app-home></app-home>`. Simply we have to write `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: Can you elaborate how?

Comment: Hi, in my case, app.component.html is the 1st UI screen. Here I show a button. Then I write <router-outlet> after this button. So on clicking the button , next component is shown just below the button in app.component.html. What I want is , On clicking the button, this button should be hidden[Means, UI of app.component.html should be hidden] and only next component is shown.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }` at the start of your `app-routing.module` rather than `'home'`, the empty string directs the app straight to `homeComponent` on load

Answer (score -1):

I'll like to use the following example to explain.
Let's say I have 3 main components:

- App component
- Home component
- Details component

The Home component(no header and footer) contains an item(name) with a "view details" button. Upon clicking on the button, we'll be taken to the Details component which contains details about the item(image, price, colors).

The template of my app component would contain only ""

My routes will look as such:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
},
{
    path: 'details',
    component: DetailsComponent
},
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo:'/home'
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: HomeComponent
}
```

With this in place, upon running the application, the Home component(containing the name of the item and the button) is rendered or displayed. Then, clicking the button(after setting the route on it) will take us to the Details component(on its own view or page)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29923208)